# Ajax .done() real execute time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to add point on image, so I use ajax to get data, but in following code, I use `map_add_beacon();` to send request, I's all right until `.done(function (beacondata)`, I want this code execute before `data.push( { x: 300, y: 300, text: 'test point1' });` , but `.done(function (beacondata)` real execute is after `var Taggd = function(element, options, data)` finished, how can I let ajax quickly execute?

Thanks!

```
var Taggd = function(element, options, data) {
        var _this = this;

        if(options.edit) {
            options.handlers = 
            {
                click: function() {
                    _this.hide();
                    methods.show.call(this);
                }
            };
        }

        this.element = $(element);
        this.options = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options);
        this.data = data;

        map_add_beacon();

        data.push( { x: 300, y: 300, text: 'test point1' });
        data.push( { x: 300, y: 400, text: 'test point2' });

        this.initialized = true;

        if(!this.element.height() || !this.element.width()) {
            this.element.on('load', _this.initialize.bind(this));
        } 
        else this.initialize();
    };

    function map_add_beacon(){
        var request = "/maps/map_beacon_assigned?locate_id=1" //access controller of interest
         //+ $('#uninstall_brand_id_select').val();
        var aj = $.ajax({
                url: request,
                type: 'get',
                beacondata: $(this).serialize()
            }).done(function (beacondata) {
                 insert_beacon(beacondata);//modify the majors' dropdown
            }).fail(function (beacondata) {
                 console.log('AJAX request has FAILED');
            });
    };

    function insert_beacon(beacondata){
        for(var i=0;i<beacondata.length;i++){
            data.push( { x: beacondata[i][0], y: beacondata[i][1], text: beacondata[i][2] });
        };
    };
```

Comment: ajax is asynchronous. You need to do the push after it completes the same way you call `insert_beacon()` in callback

Comment: I can't understand... can you explain more? do you mean that I should add something like .done function on insert_beacon?

Comment: Done function executes when the request to the url you provide to ajax function, has been done

Comment: thanks a lot, I use async: false in ajax code to solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery allows you to chain `done` methods, so you could create a separate function to contain your `data.push` code, which can then be executed after your `$.ajax.done` call.

It's unclear how your code relates to the jQuery environment. It looks like this code is expecting several jQuery methods to be present on the `this` object, but your code snippet doesn't look like plugin code. You've also got some scoping problems in your posted code (where is `done` declared or passed to your `insert_beacon` function), and you reference an `_initialize` function in your snippet that isn't actually present anywhere in your posted code. You can use this as a starting point if you wish, but it's not going to work as-is.

```js
var Taggd = function(element, options, data) {
  this.element = $(element);

  if(options.edit) {
    options.handlers = 
      {
      click: function() {
        // Where is the `hide()` method declared. Should this be `this.element.hide()`?
        this.hide();
        // What is `methods`?
        methods.show.call(this);
      }.bind(this);
    };
  }

  this.options = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options);
  this.data = data;

  // Declare functions internal to the `Taggd` object to close over the `data` object
  // for later execution
  var insert_beacon = function(beacondata){
    for(var i = 0; i < beacondata.length; i++){
      data.push( { x: beacondata[i][0], y: beacondata[i][1], text: beacondata[i][2] });
    }
  };

  var map_add_beacon = function(){
    var request = "/maps/map_beacon_assigned?locate_id=1"; //access controller of interest
    //+ $('#uninstall_brand_id_select').val();
    var aj = $.ajax({
      url: request,
      type: 'get',
      beacondata: $(this).serialize()
    })
    // jQuery allows you to chain `done` methods: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

    // modify the majors' dropdown
    .done(insert_beacon)

    // finish initialization
    .done(ajaxCallback)

    // `beacondata` isn't passed to the fail method
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
      console.log('AJAX request has FAILED with error: ', errorThrown);
    });
  }.bind(this);

  var pushExtraData = function() {
    data.push( { x: 300, y: 300, text: 'test point1' });
    data.push( { x: 300, y: 400, text: 'test point2' });
  };

  var ajaxCallback = function() {
    pushExtraData();
    this.initialized = true;
    // If anything fails here, you should reject
  }.bind(this);

  // Where is the `initialize` function declared?
  if(!this.element.height() || !this.element.width()) {
    this.element.on('load', this.initialize.bind(this));
  } else {
    this.initialize();
  }

  map_add_beacon();

};
```

Comment: I'm glad that flag works for you, but I don't actually recommend that for long-term use. The purpose of async calls is to allow other processing while the call is being fulfilled. Since JavaScript is single-threaded, a synchronous call invoked with `async:false` will block any other operations (e.g., user interactions with UI controls that rely on jQuery, other AJAX calls, etc). It's better in the long term to structure your code to properly handle async operations. Learning to think in those terms will greatly increase the problem solving tools at your disposal, too.

Comment: thanks, for me, it's a temporary solve mwthod, for long-term, I will learn to use better way! :)